# Almost everywhere convergence of orthogonal series

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, almost-everywhere

If $h_0, h_1 h_2, \ldots$ is an **orthogonal** sequence in the Hilbert space $L^2 (X, \Omega, \mu)$ such that $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \lVert h_n\rVert_2^2 < + \infty$, then does $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty h_n$ converge almost everywhere?

It is easy to see that $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty h_n$ converges in $L^2 (\mu)$ by the Riesz-Fischer theorem, and also that there is a 'subseries' that converges almost everywhere, i.e. for some increasing sequence $N_0 < N_1 < N_2 < \ldots$, the sequence $S_n = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N_n} h_{k}$ converges almost everywhere.
But can we assert anything about the original series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that there exists a subsequence
$$
\sigma_{n_k} := \sum_{j=0}^{n_k} |h_j|
$$
that converges almost everywhere in $X$.
But this implies that the series with non-negative terms $\sum_j |h_j|$ converges almost everywhere.

EDIT: under the current assumptions ($\sum_j \|h_j\|_2^2 < \infty$) this answer is no longer correct.

Comment: statement fixed.

Comment: ...and answer fixed.

Comment: Note the question has been changed - fixed a typo. With the current version there's no obvious reason that a subsequence of $\sum |h_j|$ should converge ae. Yes, a subsequence of $\sum h_j$ converges ae, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you. Now not trivial as before.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it's true, not that I have a counterexample  handy. For many years people thought this was false for trigonometric series; Carleson astounded everyone by showing that the answer is yes for trigonometric series. but this is like the hardest theorem in harmonic analysis.

Comment: Oh boy, edited the question. But @Rigel 's answer is satisfactory.

Comment: Not that it's his fault, since you changed the question. But I don't think his answer is correct with the current version! If it were correct it would be a trivial proof of Carleson's theorem.